# Reputation Tally Page No Longer Shows Recent Points

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

In the past, when I went to my profile and clicked on the tab for reputation, and went to [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tangooversway?tab=reputation) I could see my reputation points for the day.  Whenever I viewed this page, I'd see the reputation points since my last view show up at the top of the list, highlighted in yellow.

Now when I load the page, the new activity shows in yellow, but as the page finishes loading, the yellow highlighting is gone and all the entries are sorted by points per post.

With this, it's hard to tell which posts are currently the most active.

Comment: Also observed on other sites: [Highlighting of new rep broken again?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122044)

Comment: I can't reproduce here.  The page loads, the newer entries are highlighted in yellow, and stay that way.  This is under Firefox 9.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, @Keen.  I guess I should add I'm in Chrome.

Comment: That matches the linked meta post.  Looks like it's broken for webkit browsers.

Answer (score 3):

There was a behavior change in Webkit biting us here, we've adjusted some JavaScript to compensate.  Reputation highlighting should once again be sane.